# Fill empty numpy array inside for loop

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 2-D numpy array X with shape (100, 4). I want to find the sum of each row of that
array and store it inside a new numpy array x_new with shape (100,0). What I've done so far
doesn't work. Any suggestions ?. Below is my approach.

```
x_new = np.empty([100,0])
for i in range(len(X)):
    array = np.append(x_new, sum(X[i]))
```

Comment: You can just use `x_new = X.sum(axis=1)` to get an array of size 100, and then reshape that to 100x1 if you really need it to be two-dimensional.  Note that it is 100x1, not 100x0.

Comment: you can't put any values in a (100,0) shape array.  See the 0?  `np.append` is hard to use unless you really read its docs.  Even then it is slower than list append.

Comment: As a very general rule of thumb, if you find yourself using a `for` loop with numpy arrays take a step back and take a different approach, non-looping approach to your problem. There's almost always a way with numpy's vectorization and broadcasting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `sum` method on a 2d array:

```
In [8]: x = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
In [9]: x
Out[9]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
In [10]: x.sum(axis=1)
Out[10]: array([ 6, 22, 38])
In [12]: x.sum(axis=1, keepdims=True)
Out[12]: 
array([[ 6],
       [22],
       [38]])
In [13]: _.shape
Out[13]: (3, 1)
```

reference: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html